# Trying to change current user profile to custom profile

Tags: permissions

Trying to change current user profile to custom profile.
I logged in  as ABC user who is associated to a system admin profile, how to change ABC to a custom profile ?

I guess current user cannot change his own user settings, but I'm unable to do it for other users too. Cannot find drop down list of profiles instead just a link seen.

Can anyone guide me on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You can't change your own profile - you will need to have another person change you.  You could set another user up as an admin temporarily, and have that user change your profile. But you should be able to change other's profile.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your own profile is not allowed.  If you cant change other users' profiles, then you probably do not have the manage users permission enabled for the profile that you are currently logged in as.  It may be some other permission, just log in as sys admin.